# Status of CRMService Message

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working in a prevalidate plugin to grant ownership of a custom entity to a Team.  I have a specific role that allows ownership of this custom entity.  In my plugin I am using the Associate message to grant the role to the Team if this grant does not already exist.

The issue that I am seeing is that the Associate message is handled asynchronously.  The grant is not always committed before record is saved.  In these cases, I get a lacking permissions error.  The second save click always works.

Is there a callback or way to poll the results of CRMService message?  Sure, I could loop with a sleep until I see the db updated.  Hoping there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

What makes you say that Associate operates asynchronously?  I don't see [anything in the Doc that leads me to believe that it is.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.associate.aspx)  I'm wondering if CRM instead is reading the database for the rights to perform the save before the prevalidation event fires.  It then fails because the rights weren't there, but when you run it again, they are and it works successfully.

If this is the case, performing the Associate operation in the onSave of the javascript using a SOAP call would resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I will look into your javascript suggestion. I believe that it is asynchronous because when stepping through the code and on single user systems, I have no issues (the save works first time). My guess is that this is a race condition that fails only when the queue is under load.

Comment: Associate is a message type you can register a plugin against.  I'm pretty sure it is not possible for the service call to be asynchronous @mswaim.